# How to Transpose MySQL Dynamic SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, database, dynamic-sql

If I have an unknown number of columns and only one row of data, and I am using dynamic SQL to fetch this data, my question is if the selected data is **2 X n** How can I transpose it to **(n+1) X 2** where this extra 1 is the new column name?

Here is an example to make my question more clear:

Unpivoting from 
c: Columns
R: rows

```
+----+----+----+
| C1 | ...| Cn |
+----+----+----+
| R11| ...| R1n|
+----+----+----+
```

To - F1 and F2 are the names of the new columns or features-

```
+----+----+
| F1 | F2 |
+----+----+
| C1 | R11|
+----+----+
| :: | :: |
+----+----+
| :: | :: |
+----+----+
| Cn | R1n|
+----+----+
```

I am not sure if this will be helpful but here is the select statement I am currently using to fetch the data:

```
SET @name = 'USA';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '`')
                          FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
                          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'country_birth'
                            AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN
                                ('country_code', 'country_name', 'indicator_name', 
 'indicator_code')),
              ' FROM country_birth WHERE country_code = "', @name, '"');
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
```

What do I need to add or change in the previous Select statement?

Comment: To convert columns to rows/unpivot you need to select and union all.

Comment: I would handle this in application code

Comment: @Strawberry this is what I ended up doing

Comment: @P.Salmon Selection is too hard with dynamic columns